# Python looping through multiple pages on a api, and printing the content i want

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

Hello im practicing my skills, (im very new to programming) and trying to go to this api https://swapi.co/api/people/ which is a api that has data of all the star wars characters, films, planets etc, im trying to loop through all the pages, and print out all the characters
this is my code currently

```
import requests
import json


r = requests.get("https://swapi.co/api/people/")
info = r.json()
for i in info['results']:
    print(i['name'])
```

which prints out all of the characters on that page,
if you look at the link, the 'next' key holds the link to the 2 page, and so on, im trying to figure out a way to open that value and print out the characters on that page, then on that page open up the value on that one and so on and so forth, till i print out all the characters.

Comment: Take that URL and repeat what you did for the original URL?

Comment: yea, but im trying to figure out how to do it all at once, meaning looping through the first page and print the name, then loop on the 2nd and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I will first start with the code and then explain it.

```
import requests
import json
```

```
def get_and_print_data(url):
        r = requests.get(url)
        info = r.json()
        for i in info['results']:
                print(i['name'])
        if info.get('next'):
                get_and_print_data(info['next'])

get_and_print_data("https://swapi.co/api/people/")
```

The code here is pretty bad, as that method is doing way too much (getting the data, processing it, determining if there are next pages and printing the data. That's way too much logic for just one function, but for our example is ok.

So, first things first, why a function?
Because we need to execute the same actions (get, process and print data) multiple times, one per page. What changes? The url, as there is a different URL for each page. So, we will have the URL as parameter of that function.

The next few lines are from your code so I assume you are familiar to them.
Then we have that important line: `if info.get('next'):`

In dictionaries you usually retrieve data with `dictionary[key]` and that triggers and exception if the key does not exist, called **KeyError**. In that case we should have used a try/except to check if the key *next* is present. Even if this is considered the more "pythonic" way, this one with the "if" might be easier to understand.

What does the `.get('next')` do then? Well, almost the same thing, but instead of throwing and exception, it will simply return `None` if the key is not present and remember that in Python `None` is evaluated as false.

Long story short, this will check if the key **next** is present in your answer (you can see that the API returns null for missing data). If the key is present, we will call that same function with the URL for the next page and repeat until the **next** key is missing (or null) in the returned JSON.

Of course, we will have to call our function with the initial URL and let it go on from there :)

Hope this helps and everything is easy to understand!

Answer (score -1):

My solution:

```
import requests
import json

def query_api(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    info = r.json()
    return info['next'], info['results']

n, r = query_api("https://swapi.co/api/people/")

while n:
    for i in r:
        print(i['name'])
    n, r = query_api(n)
```

Also, if you're playing around with APIs like this, you may wish to take a look at [requests-cahce](https://pypi.org/project/requests-cache/) which you can include in your code to cache API results locally so you can run repeat queries without hitting a rate limits.  (And of course to be considerate to the API's owner).